# Why is il3-fw2.canonical.com Pinging a server? / Security Concern

Tags: 20.04, security, ping, canonical, unattended-upgrades

Presently, we have a number of Ubuntu 20.04 servers set up with unattended-updates, restricted just to security updates. I'm aware this generates a log, and checking said log does show that about twice a day, the script runs, looks for updates, but has not found or installed any within the last 10 days.

[Unattended Upgrades log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZI9QP.png)

That being said, we saw one machine getting pinged by il3-fw2.canonical.com on IP address 185.125.190.12 a total of 79 separate times at 16:11:40 UDT on 9 Mar 22. According to https://whois.ipinsight.io/cidr/185.125.188.0/22, this is a verified Canonical IP address - but I'm lost as to why it pinged this one particular machine so many times at once. This is only occurred on this one particular server at this location. There have been other pings since, but they have been singular pings.

My immediate concern, especially in light of current events, is that this a possible attack vector akin to the 2019-2020 SolarWinds attack, so I'm trying to get ahead of this - I just have no logical answer as to why this particular IP address is pinging the server so often and seemingly without valid reason.

Am I missing something here? Thoughts and ideas would be greatly appreciated!